# Limit of this complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to compute $\lim_{r\to\infty}I(r)$, where $I(r)$ is given as follows:

> Let $\gamma (t)=re^{it},\ 0\le t\le \pi$ and
>   $$I(r)=\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz.$$

I found this integral very hard to calculate. I've already tried to find some Cauchy theorems to use, but without success.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mean $0\le t\le 2\pi$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio not yet, unfortunately

Comment: @J.R. no, it's $t\le \pi$

Comment: @DonAntonio: The residue theorem doesn't help here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48100/discussion-between-j-r-and-donantonio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$I(r)=\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz = i \int_0^{\pi} e^{i r e^{it}} dt$$

Note that 
$$|e^{ire^{it}}| = e^{\mathrm{Re}(i r e^{it})}=e^{-r\sin(t)}.$$

Thus,

$$|I(r)|\le \int_0^\pi e^{-r\sin(t)} dt.$$

Since $|e^{-r\sin(t)}|\le 1$ and $e^{-r\sin(t)}\to 0$ for $t\in(0,\pi)$, we have by [Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) that

$$\lim_{r\to\infty} \int_0^\pi e^{-r\sin(t)} dt = 0$$

Therefore $\lim_{r\to\infty} |I(r)|$ exists and equals $0$.

*Edit*: Here is an alternative proof that $\lim_{r\to\infty} \int_0^\pi e^{-r\sin(t)} dt = 0$:

Choose some small $\epsilon>0$ and write
$$\int_0^\pi e^{-r\sin(t)} dt = \Big(\int_0^\epsilon e^{-r\sin(t)} dt + \int_{\pi-\epsilon}^\pi e^{-r\sin(t)} dt\Big) + \int_\epsilon^{\pi-\epsilon} e^{-r\sin(t)} dt.$$

Now estimate

$$\Big|\int_0^\epsilon e^{-r\sin(t)} dt + \int_{\pi-\epsilon}^\pi e^{-r\sin(t)} dt\Big| \le \int_0^\epsilon dt + \int_{\pi-\epsilon}^\epsilon dt = 2\epsilon$$

and

$$\int_\epsilon^{\pi-\epsilon} e^{-r\sin(t)} dt \le\pi e^{-r\sin(\epsilon)}.$$

Thus,

$$|I(r)|\le \int_0^\pi e^{-r\sin(t)}dt\le 2\epsilon + \pi e^{-r\sin(\epsilon)}$$

Taking $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ on both sides (the limit $\lim_{r\to\infty} |I(r)|$ exists because $|I(r)|$ is bounded and decreasing) and noting that $\sin(\epsilon)>0$:

$$\lim_{r\to\infty} |I(r)|\le 2\epsilon$$

Since this holds for all $\epsilon>0$, we have $\lim_{r\to\infty} |I(r)|=0$.

Comment: I've never studied this Lebesgue's theorem before, is it possible to solve this question using only undergraduate complex analysis? thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, you can also show directly that $\int_0^{\pi} e^{-r\sin(t)} dt$ converges to $0$ as $r\to\infty$, this is just the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Can I do this solving this integral directly? could you explain a little bit  how can I prove this convergence please?

Comment: Yes, I added details.

Comment: @user42912: Do you understand?

Comment: yes, thank you very much!!!